# Problems with UTF-8 when attaching to a tmux session over ssh

Tags: ssh, tmux, character-encoding

### Scenario:

I have a server, on which a tmux session is running. Let's call that session *`tmux_session`* in the rest of this post.

Attaching to that session can be done in two, slightly different ways:

1. By first ssh-ing to the server:

   ```
   user@host$ ssh user@server.tld
   ```

   and then attaching to the named session:

   ```
   user@server$ tmux a -d -t tmux_session
   ```
2. By ssh-ing and attaching at the same time:

   ```
   user@host$ ssh user@server.tld -t tmux -a -d -t tmux_session
   ```

### Symptoms:

**Method №1** works as expected. My `LANG` is set to `C.UTF-8`, `echo`-ing it inside `tmux_session` works fine, and it's reported correctly. Unicode input of characters like "¹²³¤", works perfectly fine.

**Method №2** yields a session, which is unable to display Unicode characters, beyond simple ASCII. All other characters get replaced by `_` (an underscore). However when *entering* a special character, the character is actually entered into whatever application is running inside `tmux_session`, I confirmed it using editors, an IRC client, etc. When I detach and re-attach using method №1, the previously entered character is displayed correctly.

This problem when using method №2, only happens when attaching to the session with the ssh command, and it only affects the display of the characters, not the actual characters being entered.

Some of the output inside `tmux` is kinda broken both times, though. When I enter `echo $LANG` inside `tmux_session` using **either** method, I see this:

```
$ echo $LANG                            
cho C.UTF-8C.UTF-8
```

Something is garbled, for some reason the input line is (partially) repeated. I read in another post on superuser.com, that one should try by first deleting `.tmux.conf`. I don't have a `.tmux.conf`, so not having that file doesn't seem to alleviate the issue for me. In any event, `$LANG` being set to `C.UTF-8` is correct.

This garbled output does not happen, when just ssh-ing to the server.

Comment: You should check the environment *outside* tmux and see if they are different between the two; at the least, `ssh -t host command` probably does not load profile, but there may be other differences. Checking *inside* the tmux session will show a mix of the configuration where the tmux server was originally started and your standard shell initialisation, which may give different results again, but less relevant ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're checking the locale settings inside the `tmux` sessions, but not those that `tmux` itself receives.

`server.ltd` likely doesn't have `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*` in its `sshd_config` or/and you don't have `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in your `ssh_config`, so the fact that your local system and terminal is using UTF-8 as the charset is not transmitted to the remote `tmux` client.

You could work around it by doing:

```
ssh -t user@server.tld "
  set -o allexport
  $(locale | grep -v '"')
  exec tmux -a -d -t tmux_session"
```

(assuming the local shell and the login shell of the remote user are POSIX-like)

Or just hardcode the UTF-8 locale of your choice if you know your terminal is talking in UTF-8:

```
ssh -t user@server.tld 'exec env LANG=C.UTF-8 tmux -a -d -t tmux_session'
```

(a syntax understood by all shells).

Comment: Thanks, the hardcoded UTF-8 locale does it for me (as my Alpine Linux doesn't have `locale` installed, and I'd like to keep things minimal). I'll see if changing the `*_config`s will fix my issue, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tmux -u` to force output of utf-8 even if $LANG is not set correctly.